# Run Spring Boot application once and exit

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot application which works ok. Now I want to add on-demand feature to import some data from file on disc (it'll be used once and never again). I have database connection, DTO objects etc ready to use, also the method to import data. 
I would like to start my application, for example with command line switch (for example -file path/to/file). It should make an app start, execute my import method, and shutdown.
The best would be not to start embedded Tomcat.

I was thinking about separate main class annotated @SpringBootApplication, and about running with -classpath, but I don't know it's good idea.

Now I think it's better to make small separated project, but maybe there's a nice feature, which allow me to run my app once and execute import method.

Answer (score 8):

you can use Spring's `CommandLineRunner` interface for that:

for example (Taken from [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app)):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication 
  implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
      .getLogger(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
        LOG.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        LOG.info("EXECUTING : command line runner");

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            LOG.info("args[{}]: {}", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similiar with SpringBoot and JCommander as addition, it makes creating CLI applications really easy and provides a lot more additional features than the CommandLineRunner Interface.

-> http://jcommander.org/